# Thank you in advance OR should it be advanced?

Tags: difference

What is the correct way to say and write:

- thank you in advance OR
- thank you in advance**d**

Is there any difference between them?

Comment: advanced (what)?

Answer (score 4):

'*In advance*' here is an adverb or more accurately a prepositional phrase and means ahead of time. In the case of 'Thanking you in advance', it implies a favour has been asked for and you're thanking them before it is fulfilled.

'*Advanced*' is an adjective and cannot be used in this context. It can only be used to describe a noun indicating that it's ahead of it's time or at a higher level when compared to the context.

'*Advanced weapons*' or '*advanced technology*' are describing the nouns weapons and technology respectively over here.